# the functor that goes the opposite direction of Spec.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$
Let $X=V(I)$, with $I \subset \C[x_1,..x_n]$ and $Y=V(J)$ with $J \subset \C[x_1,...x_m]$.  Say a map $\phi:X \to Y$ is regular if there are polynomials $f_1(x_1...x_n),...,f_m(x_1,...x_n)$ such that the restriction to $X$ has its image in  $Y$.

In this case one can define a ring homomorphism $\Phi:\C[x_1,...,x_m]/J \to \C[x_1,...x_n]/I$ via $f \mapsto f \circ \phi$.

Question:  Given commutative rings $R$ and $S$, when does a map $Spec S \to Spec R$ define a ring homomorphism $R \to S$.

I think this is very standard.  But google is failing me.  And I don't want to ask a professor because she will think that I am asking a question that I know the answer to.  A reference to a place in the stacksproject where this is dealt with would be very much appreciated.  Of course I would be delighted to get an answer too.

Background:  Did well in a varieties course.  Doing commutative algebra now.

Comment: The category of affine scheme is (anti) equivalent to the category of rings, as the categories of affine varieties over a field is (anti) equivalent to the categories of the reduced, finitely-generated $k$-algebras. The functor from the scheme to the ring is the global section functor. It induce a map of global sections which is the map your are looking for. This is the really first thing you need to know about affine scheme.

Comment: I thought that there is no functor from finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$ algebras to Varieties over $\C$.  I don't think there is any morphism of varieties that corresponds to a ring homomorphism $\Phi:\C[x_1,...,x_m]/J \to \C[x_1,...x_n]/I$, when $\phi^{-1}$ of a maximal ideal is not maximal.  But thanks everyone for the answers.  Sorry for being a waste of your time.

Comment: No worries ! This is in Hartshorne, page 19. The only condition is that $\Phi$ is a morphism of $k$ algebra (i.e a morphism of rings which is the identity on $k$.)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is always. The data of a map $f: \mathrm{Spec} S\to \mathrm{Spec} R$ is a continuous map of topological spaces plus a map of sheaves $f^\#: \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}R}\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec} S}$. Applying global sections to this map of sheaves gives a map of rings $R\to S$.

The explanation of this is that the categories of affine schemes and rings are equivalent via the functors $\mathrm{Spec}$ and global sections. You can read more about this at http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01HX

Answer (score 1):

Well there are these old things called books. Anyway if you have a map of sheaves $f:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ then there is an induced map of the global sections $\Gamma(f):\Gamma(\mathcal{G})\rightarrow \Gamma(\mathcal{F})$. And the ring of section of $spec (R)$ is $R$.